# I've an error in ionic when I try to build android

Tags: ionic-framework

> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
>   setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'.
>   Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

and my path is

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/shahbaz/android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

please give me solution

Comment: Check using %ANDROID_HOME% if you get to see the Android home

Comment: Check whether android sdk is in path you specified and also be sure it has been added to environment path